# What's the difference between the ruby irb prompt modes?

Tags: ruby, irb

I can change the irb prompt mode with

```
irb --prompt prompt-mode
```

I can see what `null` and `simple` does, but I can't tell the difference between `null` and `xmp` and the difference between `default`/`classic`/`inf-ruby`. Can someone explain to me what these other modes do? It seems pointless to have multiple modes doing the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to those questions lie in IRB.conf[:PROMPT] which is a hash whose keys are the different prompts and whose values are the configurations for each prompt. [Read this to a understand a prompt's configuration](http://tagaholic.me/2009/05/29/exploring-how-to-configure-irb.html#prompt).

The difference between null and xmp is that xmp displays a result indented with an arrow:

```
$ irb --prompt xmp -f
2**10
    ==>1024
```

while null doesn't indent or display the arrow:

```
$ irb --prompt null -f
2**10
1024
```

You should be able to answer your second question once you read the above link and understand that prompts have different modes and different configurations for them.

Answer (score 8):

Once you read the article cldwalker posted above, you may want to design a custom prompt, here's mine for example:

```
IRB.conf[:PROMPT][:CUSTOM] = {
  :PROMPT_I => ">> ",
  :PROMPT_S => "%l>> ",
  :PROMPT_C => ".. ",
  :PROMPT_N => ".. ",
  :RETURN => "=> %s\n"
}
IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :CUSTOM
IRB.conf[:AUTO_INDENT] = true
```