# irb command line prefix remove

Tags: ruby, irb

I just updated my ruby version and now when I run irb in command line, I get this weird:

```
1.9.2p290 :001 >
```

every line. Before it was a simple `>`

How can I get it back again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your `~/.irbrc` file to change the prompt (command line prefix). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2468300/86871) for an example. You could put this in there to start:

```
IRB.conf[:PROMPT][:CUSTOM] = {:PROMPT_I => ">> "}
IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :CUSTOM
IRB.conf[:AUTO_INDENT] = true
```

`.irbrc` is a Ruby script that irb runs when it starts up that lets you configure your prompt.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work in 2.3. `NoMethodError: undefined method 'write' for nil:NilClass`. See the answer by @user1179942

Answer (score 2):

From [this article](http://linux.die.net/man/1/irb), in your user dir `~/`, create the `.irbrc` file with following:

```
IRB.conf[:PROMPT][:MY_PROMPT] = { # name of prompt mode
  :PROMPT_I => ">",          # normal prompt
  :PROMPT_S => nil,          # prompt for continuated strings
  :PROMPT_C => nil,          # prompt for continuated statement
  :RETURN => "=> %s\n"       # format to return value
}
IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :MY_PROMPT
```